# VISA Waiving Program changes

Tags: usa, europe, international-travel, us-visa-waiver-program

Regarding the new changes to the VWP to travel to the U.S. Does anybody know if it is 5 years starting the effective date or anyone visited one of those countries afte March 1st 2011? In other word if an EU journalist visited Iraq April 2011, is he going to be able to travel to the US under VWP after April 2016?

Also do you think EU will retaliate against Americans under the same category ? Thought appreciated...

Comment: The last paragraph is off topic as "primarily opinion based" -- the site is designed to discourage open-ended discussions.

Answer (score 1):

From [United States Begins Implementation of Changes to the Visa Waiver Program](https://www.dhs.gov/news/2016/01/21/united-states-begins-implementation-changes-visa-waiver-program), the new restrictions apply to:

> Nationals of VWP countries who have traveled to or been present in Iran, Iraq, Sudan, or Syria on or after March 1, 2011 (with limited exceptions for travel for diplomatic or military purposes in the service of a VWP country).

So the new restriction appears to apply to anyone who has traveled to those countries since March 1, 2011.

However, this page also says:

> Under the new law, the Secretary of Homeland Security may waive these restrictions if he determines that such a waiver is in the law enforcement or national security interests of the United States. Such waivers will be granted only on a case-by-case basis. As a general matter, categories of travelers who may be eligible for a waiver include:
>
> - Individuals who traveled to Iran, Iraq, Sudan or Syria as a journalist for reporting purposes;

It is unclear at this point how one might actually apply for such a waiver, or whether such a procedure might be any easier than simply applying for a normal visa.

Comment: So did this law pass? That is so sad. And seems quite random to me: visited Afghanistan and received training from the Taliban? Here's your ESTA! Went to see Persepolis? How dare you, you damned terrorist!!!